Is it possible to create a Page with navigation of ListViews on the left and Lists on the right?
The navigation of ListViews on the left I have, but once I want to show the list on the right side, it navigates the entire page, instead of showing it in a view. See the idea below, with description.

I tried several options, using LWC and NavigationMixins, an iFrame, datatables (but columns of the fields do not load dynamically from the view, I have to specify them manually for each view).
The solution needs to be automated, so that the columns are known from the views. Ideally the List on the right side would be a "start and go" feature from Salesforce itself.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is what I would recommend. 1) LWC component 1 - left side to show nested view of list views 2) LWC component 2 - right side to display the details. You can use events Pubsub to dispatch an event from the LWC 1, LWC 2 would listen for the event and display the details. Put the two components in a lightning page, use field sets to control displaying fields etc . Happy to help with more details if you need

Whereas LWC doesn't have an out-of-the-box "List View" component, Aura has. This is one of the few situations, where it is still best to use Aura. Below the code for both the Aura component that utilizes Salesforce's List View component and a child LWC that generates the list of buttons you show on the left side. I include the latter in my answer to facilitate testing my code.
Markup Aura:
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="objectApiName" type="String" default="Account"/>
    <aura:attribute name="listName" type="String" />
    <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
        <div class="slds-col">
            <c:listViews onlistviewclicked="{!c.handleListViewClicked}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col">
             <aura:if isTrue="{!v.listName != null}">
                <lightning:listView 
                    aura:id="listView"
                    objectApiName="{!v.objectApiName}"
                    listName="{!v.listName}"
                />
            </aura:if>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>

Aura Controller:
({
    handleListViewClicked : function(component, event) {
        const listViewApiName = event.getParam('apiName');
        setTimeout(() => component.set("v.listName", listViewApiName) , 0);
        component.set("v.listName", null);
    }
})

You didn't include your attempts in the text of your question. I suspect that you tried the above and just missed the bit that makes Javascript wait 0 seconds, i.e. execute the listName update asynchronously. The lightning:listView component is a bit of a slacker and otherwise doesn't get its stuff together.
Markup LWC (for the buttons on the left):
<template>
    <template for:each={listViews} for:item="listView" lwc:if={showListViews}>
        <div key={listView.apiName}>
            <lightning-button label={listView.label} onclick={handleClick} value={listView.id}></lightning-button>
        </div>
    </template>
</template>

Javascript LWC (informing the Aura component about chosen list views):
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getListInfosByObjectName } from "lightning/uiListsApi";

export default class ListViews extends LightningElement {

    listViews;

    get showListViews() {
        return this.listViews && this.listViews.length > 0;
    }

    @wire(getListInfosByObjectName, {
        objectApiName: 'Account'
    })
    listOfLists({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.listViews = data.lists;
        } else if (error) {
            console.error('error => ', error);
        }
    }

    handleClick(event) {
        const clickedListView = this.listViews.find(listView => listView.id === event.target.value);
        const customEvent = new CustomEvent("listviewclicked", {
            detail: {apiName: clickedListView.apiName}
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(customEvent);
    }
}

The above example uses the Account object, but is deliberately shaped in a way that facilitates making the choice of the object dynamic.
On using LWC
Why didn't I suggest to go LWC-only, and wire getListRecordsByName? If you want to render anything closely resembling Salesforce's "List View" on the right side, you will need some sort of Lightning Datatable. This results in considerable overhead.

E.g. if you use the out-of-the-box solution from Salesforce, you'd need to dynamically map table field types to field types of the fields of your respective SObject. Which requires another @wire call. Etc.

If you want a very simple "List View" on the right side, you could use Salesforce's markup suggestions and wrap your Javascript around it. But then you would need to work on your field output, e.g. Date formats. And more.


That being said, if you don't need "the" List View at all, but just some "view of a list" (and maybe even don't mind how field values are represented) - go for LWC!

Thank you very much! I will try it. I need to gain some new reputation to upvote :)

Seems to work, I am excited!

Thank you for the feedback! Glad it worked.

[UiListsApi][1]
you can try using below APIs
[1]: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/reference-lightning-ui-api-lists-ui.html

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
